# Cannot find vars set by `DefinePlugin`

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to move application into TS, but have been getting this error in my `index.tsx`:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name '__DEVELOPMENT__'.
```

The code that throws that error:

```
console.warn('__DEVELOPMENT__', __DEVELOPMENT__);
if (__DEVELOPMENT__) {

}
```

The `__DEVELOPMENT__` var is set by webpack's `DefinePlugin` and pretty much is `env.NODE_ENV === 'development'`, but I've tried multiple things to solve it but still getting that error.

I've declared `globals.d.ts`, like so:
`declare const __DEVELOPMENT__: boolean;`
but without luck.

My webpack config with `DefinePlugin`:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __DEVELOPMENT__: env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
});
```

Anybody knows how to fix that ?

Comment: Would be helpful to post your webpack configuration here

Comment: let me update my question @Teedeez

Comment: Change `env.NODE_ENV === 'development'` to `JSON.stringify(env.NODE_ENV === 'development')`. You can read [this page](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) as to why you must `JSON.stringify` the value, and don't forget to keep the variable declaration in the `.d.ts` file

Comment: @Teedeez, same error :(

Comment: So if TypeScript fails to compile your code because it can't find `__DEVELOPMENT__`, it sure means that it is not picking up your declaration in `globals.d.ts`, so look inside your `tsconfig.json` file, find `rootDir` or `rootDirs` property, and make sure that your `.d.ts` file is in a directory that is under `rootDir` or `rootDirs`